# Benchmarking Linux flash player and google chrome built in flash player

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, flash

I use xubuntu 14.04 64 bit, I installed flash player from software center and xubuntu-restricted-extras too

Are there any benchmarks on Linux flash player and google chrome built in flash player? I just want to see their performance because in theory google's flash player should be more updated and have better performance than the one we use in Firefox. (that's what I read everywhere)

I have chrome latest version installed and Firefox next, and I found that flash videos in Chrome are laggy and they take long time to load. While the same flash videos load much faster in Firefox and I tend to prefer watching flash videos in firefox, especially the long ones because it loads them so much faster.

I can't believe these results on my PC, so is there any  way to benchmark flash players performance on both browsers? I want to know if it's because of the flash player or the browsers or something else

Comment: [This thing](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/465908) was the first thing I found - I scored 13146 in Firefox on Fedora 19 on my laptop. Something running in Flash Player is likely to be the best way to benchmark it, i suppose like the [Acid3 test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) for browsers. There are likely to be better tests than this though.

Comment: @Wilf the fist test ff 12065 chrome 76435, second test both 100/100 strange results

Comment: acid3 test is a completely different test for rendering in browsers :) - With flash, Chrome should generally do better due to different implementation, later version, i think it also has support for hardware acceleration - but it does have a few problems anyway - shall i put the comment above as an answer or have you found anything?

Comment: @Wilf yes answer it why not and I'll continue digging tomorrow and get back to you coz it's almost 2 am here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/465908) was the first thing I found - I scored the following on Fedora 19 on my laptop:

**Firefox 29 - Flash Player 11.2.202.359**
[image: firefox]

**Chrome 35 - Flash Player 13.0.0.214**
[image: chrome]

So it looks pretty bad for Firefox with the system Linux plugin - however, just as I was writing this, this happened in Chrome where I had left the test open (annoying music muted): 
[image: flash crash error]

And since I have has this quite often before (occasionally on Ubuntu as well), I think Flash in Firefox generally works MUCH better (and more reliably, loads quicker, etc...)

A test in Flash Player is likely to be the best way to benchmark it, as I suppose the [Acid3 test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) is a good way to benchmark browsers. There are likely to be better tests than this though.

Comment: Yes same chrome issue here.... btw offtopic question why fedora? Gnome or kde? Slackware man!   I want to try a kde distro either netrunner or opensue or fedora. You seem to like yum and centos servers like me

Comment: Fedora just works.... Ubuntu on this laptop kept being silly during boot, where as this takes half a minute at most to boot (as use less battery). Also because I can use Gnome 3.8 without having to go to Ubuntu 13.10 or something, and I just hate apt with dependcy silliness even though its easier to use than rpms etc... I could go on even more :-)

Comment: yes I don't like ubuntu either, I'm using xubuntu which is supposed to be fast, still slow on boot compared to manjaro or crunchbang, takes too much time and it freezes sometimes on shut down, so on, the only reason I'm using it is because of askubuntu large community and because of LTS, I couldn't get manjaro wireless drivers to work on my pc, I should give it another try, maybe I can get a rolling release working on my pc, I wouldve used fedora if they had longer support, I hate upgrading to new version, it breaks many stuff