# Adobe Flash Trouble

Tags: 14.04, flash

Browser games such as King's Road won't run in Linux for me, because I need to download Adobe Flash 12.0 apparently, but when I follow the links given in the dialog box where I am informed of this, none of the options to download seem to render any results.

The option to download for linux 10.0 + is simply unresponsive and the options that are responsive only download a folder with what is apparently nothing but text files.

I am new to Linux and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the Google Chrome browser?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe [stopped support for Flash for Linux](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/adobe-abandons-linux/10418) - apart from the odd bug/security fix, it'll be stuck at version 11.2 (11.2 r202 I think at the moment).

This means if you want a more recent version of Flash, you need to use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), which has an [embedded version of Flash](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en). This can be a bit buggy and crash, but it can also be quite a lot faster due to hardware acceleration support etc - as sort of shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/474159/178596).

Another options would be to use [PipeLight](http://pipelight.net/cms/about.html), which imitates Windows (or something) to use the latest version of Flash:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Trusty, Pepper Flash (Flash 13.0), which Google Chrome uses, is available in the repos, and you can use this Flash in Google Chrome and Chromium (the latter also available in the repos).

Pepper Flash:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Chromium:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```